# Accumulation points in topology

Tags: general-topology

I have a small problem in a question that has many demands. so, one of the demands is accumulation points, and I decided my answer but I am not so sure.
So, if you just helped me a little I will be thankful,
The question is:

> Let $\mathbb{R}$ be a set of all real numbers and $\tau$ consists of $\mathbb{R}, \emptyset$ and all open intervals $(-n,n)$ for $n$ any positive integer. Let $A=(-\infty,4)$ then, find derive set of $A$ (Limit points of $A$)

1. I decided my answer that $d(A)=(-\infty,4]$
2. But my issue is we have $(-n,n)$ in $\tau$, so I confused that the answer might be $d(A)=(-\infty,4)$ because of $(-n,n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every non-empty open sets $U$ intersects $A = (-\infty, 4)$ at infinity many points, the derive set of $A$ is the whole space $\mathbb R$.

Comment: So u say that the limit points of A are [4, ∞) because if we say that the closure of A is R then we know that Cl(A)=A ∪ d(A), but how closure of A is R, i think closure of A is (- ∞,4] or no !!

Comment: which parts of my answer do you not agree with? I just proved that the closure is $\mathbb R$. @user517932

Comment: when u say that the closure is $\mathbb R$ so what the $d(A) will be ?? I just want to know the Limit Points of $A$ !!

Comment: Is that okay now @user517932

Comment: It is clear now , thanks